# Extract list values to standardized data frame

Tags: r, dataframe, sapply

I have a list object with many separate lists of values that are at most of length 12. Not all have length 12 (as seen in the data below).

I would like to extract the values into an x*12 data frame, where x is the number of lists (so 50 in this case). If the list does not have all 12 values, I hope to input a blank. So if there's only one value (like in row 35), that would go in the 35th row and 1st column, and the 2nd-12th columns for that row would have blanks inserted.

So far, my efforts have focused on things like test105 below to account for the varying number of rows and columns. Is there a way to standardize beforehand to allow for the dataframe format?

```
 test105=sapply(test99,"[[",1)
```

I also converted the list structure "test99" with the as.matrix command, but that doesn't seem to give me more flexibility other than seeing the data more clearly.

Thank you for the help.

```
 dput(test99transfer)
 structure(list(`1` = structure(c("3.631412983", "1.351914048", 
"-1.82656002", "-3.531716108", "0.468971014", "-0.510936022", 
"2.025001049", "4.369469166", "0.574441016", "-0.397388995", 
"3.314476013", "2.016448021"), .Names = c("Feb 2012", "Mar 2012", 
"Apr 2012", "May 2012", "Jun 2012", "Jul 2012", "Aug 2012", "Sep 2012", 
"Oct 2012", "Nov 2012", "Dec 2012", "Jan 2013")), `2` = structure(c("1.351914048", 
"-1.82656002", "-3.531716108", "0.468971014", "-0.510936022", 
"2.025001049", "4.369469166", "0.574441016", "-0.397388995", 
"3.314476013", "2.016448021", "0.041545"), .Names = c("Mar 2012", 
"Apr 2012", "May 2012", "Jun 2012", "Jul 2012", "Aug 2012", "Sep 2012", 
"Oct 2012", "Nov 2012", "Dec 2012", "Jan 2013", "Feb 2013")), 
`3` = structure(c("-1.82656002", "-3.531716108", "0.468971014", 
"-0.510936022", "2.025001049", "4.369469166", "0.574441016", 
"-0.397388995", "3.314476013", "2.016448021", "0.041545", 
"1.944175005"), .Names = c("Apr 2012", "May 2012", "Jun 2012", 
"Jul 2012", "Aug 2012", "Sep 2012", "Oct 2012", "Nov 2012", 
"Dec 2012", "Jan 2013", "Feb 2013", "Mar 2013")), `4` = structure(c("-3.531716108", 
"0.468971014", "-0.510936022", "2.025001049", "4.369469166", 
"0.574441016", "-0.397388995", "3.314476013", "2.016448021", 
"0.041545", "1.944175005", "0.898332"), .Names = c("May 2012", 
"Jun 2012", "Jul 2012", "Aug 2012", "Sep 2012", "Oct 2012", 
"Nov 2012", "Dec 2012", "Jan 2013", "Feb 2013", "Mar 2013", 
"Apr 2013")), `5` = structure(c("0.468971014", "-0.510936022", 
"2.025001049", "4.369469166", "0.574441016", "-0.397388995", 
"3.314476013", "2.016448021", "0.041545", "1.944175005", 
"0.898332", "1.043239951"), .Names = c("Jun 2012", "Jul 2012", 
"Aug 2012", "Sep 2012", "Oct 2012", "Nov 2012", "Dec 2012", 
"Jan 2013", "Feb 2013", "Mar 2013", "Apr 2013", "May 2013"
)), `6` = structure(c("-0.510936022", "2.025001049", "4.369469166", 
"0.574441016", "-0.397388995", "3.314476013", "2.016448021", 
"0.041545", "1.944175005", "0.898332", "1.043239951", "0.722914994"
), .Names = c("Jul 2012", "Aug 2012", "Sep 2012", "Oct 2012", 
"Nov 2012", "Dec 2012", "Jan 2013", "Feb 2013", "Mar 2013", 
"Apr 2013", "May 2013", "Jun 2013")), `7` = structure(c("2.025001049", 
"4.369469166", "0.574441016", "-0.397388995", "3.314476013", 
"2.016448021", "0.041545", "1.944175005", "0.898332", "1.043239951", 
"0.722914994", "-0.349180996"), .Names = c("Aug 2012", "Sep 2012", 
"Oct 2012", "Nov 2012", "Dec 2012", "Jan 2013", "Feb 2013", 
"Mar 2013", "Apr 2013", "May 2013", "Jun 2013", "Jul 2013"
)), `8` = structure(c("4.369469166", "0.574441016", "-0.397388995", 
"3.314476013", "2.016448021", "0.041545", "1.944175005", 
"0.898332", "1.043239951", "0.722914994", "-0.349180996", 
"0.074822001"), .Names = c("Sep 2012", "Oct 2012", "Nov 2012", 
"Dec 2012", "Jan 2013", "Feb 2013", "Mar 2013", "Apr 2013", 
"May 2013", "Jun 2013", "Jul 2013", "Aug 2013")), `9` = structure(c("0.574441016", 
"-0.397388995", "3.314476013", "2.016448021", "0.041545", 
"1.944175005", "0.898332", "1.043239951", "0.722914994", 
"-0.349180996", "0.074822001", "-1.258324027"), .Names = c("Oct 2012", 
"Nov 2012", "Dec 2012", "Jan 2013", "Feb 2013", "Mar 2013", 
"Apr 2013", "May 2013", "Jun 2013", "Jul 2013", "Aug 2013", 
"Sep 2013")), `10` = structure(c("-0.397388995", "3.314476013", 
"2.016448021", "0.041545", "1.944175005", "0.898332", "1.043239951", 
"0.722914994", "-0.349180996", "0.074822001", "-1.258324027", 
"1.153113008"), .Names = c("Nov 2012", "Dec 2012", "Jan 2013", 
"Feb 2013", "Mar 2013", "Apr 2013", "May 2013", "Jun 2013", 
"Jul 2013", "Aug 2013", "Sep 2013", "Oct 2013")), `11` = structure(c("3.314476013", 
"2.016448021", "0.041545", "1.944175005", "0.898332", "1.043239951", 
"0.722914994", "-0.349180996", "0.074822001", "-1.258324027", 
"1.153113008", "1.344225049"), .Names = c("Dec 2012", "Jan 2013", 
"Feb 2013", "Mar 2013", "Apr 2013", "May 2013", "Jun 2013", 
"Jul 2013", "Aug 2013", "Sep 2013", "Oct 2013", "Nov 2013"
)), `12` = structure(c("2.016448021", "0.041545", "1.944175005", 
"0.898332", "1.043239951", "0.722914994", "-0.349180996", 
"0.074822001", "-1.258324027", "1.153113008", "1.344225049", 
"2.703722954"), .Names = c("Jan 2013", "Feb 2013", "Mar 2013", 
"Apr 2013", "May 2013", "Jun 2013", "Jul 2013", "Aug 2013", 
"Sep 2013", "Oct 2013", "Nov 2013", "Dec 2013")), `13` = structure(c("0.041545", 
"1.944175005", "0.898332", "1.043239951", "0.722914994", 
"-0.349180996", "0.074822001", "-1.258324027", "1.153113008", 
"1.344225049", "2.703722954", "-1.334722042"), .Names = c("Feb 2013", 
"Mar 2013", "Apr 2013", "May 2013", "Jun 2013", "Jul 2013", 
"Aug 2013", "Sep 2013", "Oct 2013", "Nov 2013", "Dec 2013", 
"Jan 2014")), `14` = structure(c("1.944175005", "0.898332", 
"1.043239951", "0.722914994", "-0.349180996", "0.074822001", 
"-1.258324027", "1.153113008", "1.344225049", "2.703722954", 
"-1.334722042", "1.17830801"), .Names = c("Mar 2013", "Apr 2013", 
"May 2013", "Jun 2013", "Jul 2013", "Aug 2013", "Sep 2013", 
"Oct 2013", "Nov 2013", "Dec 2013", "Jan 2014", "Feb 2014"
)), `15` = structure(c("0.898332", "1.043239951", "0.722914994", 
"-0.349180996", "0.074822001", "-1.258324027", "1.153113008", 
"1.344225049", "2.703722954", "-1.334722042", "1.17830801", 
"1.743324995"), .Names = c("Apr 2013", "May 2013", "Jun 2013", 
"Jul 2013", "Aug 2013", "Sep 2013", "Oct 2013", "Nov 2013", 
"Dec 2013", "Jan 2014", "Feb 2014", "Mar 2014")), `16` = structure(c("1.043239951", 
"0.722914994", "-0.349180996", "0.074822001", "-1.258324027", 
"1.153113008", "1.344225049", "2.703722954", "-1.334722042", 
"1.17830801", "1.743324995", "0.075165004"), .Names = c("May 2013", 
"Jun 2013", "Jul 2013", "Aug 2013", "Sep 2013", "Oct 2013", 
"Nov 2013", "Dec 2013", "Jan 2014", "Feb 2014", "Mar 2014", 
"Apr 2014")), `17` = structure(c("0.722914994", "-0.349180996", 
"0.074822001", "-1.258324027", "1.153113008", "1.344225049", 
"2.703722954", "-1.334722042", "1.17830801", "1.743324995", 
"0.075165004", "0.368221998"), .Names = c("Jun 2013", "Jul 2013", 
"Aug 2013", "Sep 2013", "Oct 2013", "Nov 2013", "Dec 2013", 
"Jan 2014", "Feb 2014", "Mar 2014", "Apr 2014", "May 2014"
)), `18` = structure(c("-0.349180996", "0.074822001", "-1.258324027", 
"1.153113008", "1.344225049", "2.703722954", "-1.334722042", 
"1.17830801", "1.743324995", "0.075165004", "0.368221998", 
"1.140485048"), .Names = c("Jul 2013", "Aug 2013", "Sep 2013", 
"Oct 2013", "Nov 2013", "Dec 2013", "Jan 2014", "Feb 2014", 
"Mar 2014", "Apr 2014", "May 2014", "Jun 2014")), `19` = structure(c("0.074822001", 
"-1.258324027", "1.153113008", "1.344225049", "2.703722954", 
"-1.334722042", "1.17830801", "1.743324995", "0.075165004", 
"0.368221998", "1.140485048", "-0.521915972"), .Names = c("Aug 2013", 
"Sep 2013", "Oct 2013", "Nov 2013", "Dec 2013", "Jan 2014", 
"Feb 2014", "Mar 2014", "Apr 2014", "May 2014", "Jun 2014", 
"Jul 2014")), `20` = structure(c("-1.258324027", "1.153113008", 
"1.344225049", "2.703722954", "-1.334722042", "1.17830801", 
"1.743324995", "0.075165004", "0.368221998", "1.140485048", 
"-0.521915972", "0.721825004"), .Names = c("Sep 2013", "Oct 2013", 
"Nov 2013", "Dec 2013", "Jan 2014", "Feb 2014", "Mar 2014", 
"Apr 2014", "May 2014", "Jun 2014", "Jul 2014", "Aug 2014"
)), `21` = structure(c("1.153113008", "1.344225049", "2.703722954", 
"-1.334722042", "1.17830801", "1.743324995", "0.075165004", 
"0.368221998", "1.140485048", "-0.521915972", "0.721825004", 
"-0.468360007"), .Names = c("Oct 2013", "Nov 2013", "Dec 2013", 
"Jan 2014", "Feb 2014", "Mar 2014", "Apr 2014", "May 2014", 
"Jun 2014", "Jul 2014", "Aug 2014", "Sep 2014")), `22` = structure(c("1.344225049", 
"2.703722954", "-1.334722042", "1.17830801", "1.743324995", 
"0.075165004", "0.368221998", "1.140485048", "-0.521915972", 
"0.721825004", "-0.468360007", "0.696716011"), .Names = c("Nov 2013", 
"Dec 2013", "Jan 2014", "Feb 2014", "Mar 2014", "Apr 2014", 
"May 2014", "Jun 2014", "Jul 2014", "Aug 2014", "Sep 2014", 
"Oct 2014")), `23` = structure(c("2.703722954", "-1.334722042", 
"1.17830801", "1.743324995", "0.075165004", "0.368221998", 
"1.140485048", "-0.521915972", "0.721825004", "-0.468360007", 
"0.696716011", "-0.181444004"), .Names = c("Dec 2013", "Jan 2014", 
"Feb 2014", "Mar 2014", "Apr 2014", "May 2014", "Jun 2014", 
"Jul 2014", "Aug 2014", "Sep 2014", "Oct 2014", "Nov 2014"
)), `24` = structure(c("-1.334722042", "1.17830801", "1.743324995", 
"0.075165004", "0.368221998", "1.140485048", "-0.521915972", 
"0.721825004", "-0.468360007", "0.696716011", "-0.181444004", 
"0.585435987"), .Names = c("Jan 2014", "Feb 2014", "Mar 2014", 
"Apr 2014", "May 2014", "Jun 2014", "Jul 2014", "Aug 2014", 
"Sep 2014", "Oct 2014", "Nov 2014", "Dec 2014")), `25` = structure(c("1.17830801", 
"1.743324995", "0.075165004", "0.368221998", "1.140485048", 
"-0.521915972", "0.721825004", "-0.468360007", "0.696716011", 
"-0.181444004", "0.585435987"), .Names = c("Feb 2014", "Mar 2014", 
"Apr 2014", "May 2014", "Jun 2014", "Jul 2014", "Aug 2014", 
"Sep 2014", "Oct 2014", "Nov 2014", "Dec 2014")), `26` = structure(c("1.743324995", 
"0.075165004", "0.368221998", "1.140485048", "-0.521915972", 
"0.721825004", "-0.468360007", "0.696716011", "-0.181444004", 
"0.585435987"), .Names = c("Mar 2014", "Apr 2014", "May 2014", 
"Jun 2014", "Jul 2014", "Aug 2014", "Sep 2014", "Oct 2014", 
"Nov 2014", "Dec 2014")), `27` = structure(c("0.075165004", 
"0.368221998", "1.140485048", "-0.521915972", "0.721825004", 
"-0.468360007", "0.696716011", "-0.181444004", "0.585435987"
), .Names = c("Apr 2014", "May 2014", "Jun 2014", "Jul 2014", 
"Aug 2014", "Sep 2014", "Oct 2014", "Nov 2014", "Dec 2014"
)), `28` = structure(c("0.368221998", "1.140485048", "-0.521915972", 
"0.721825004", "-0.468360007", "0.696716011", "-0.181444004", 
"0.585435987"), .Names = c("May 2014", "Jun 2014", "Jul 2014", 
"Aug 2014", "Sep 2014", "Oct 2014", "Nov 2014", "Dec 2014"
)), `29` = structure(c("1.140485048", "-0.521915972", "0.721825004", 
"-0.468360007", "0.696716011", "-0.181444004", "0.585435987"
), .Names = c("Jun 2014", "Jul 2014", "Aug 2014", "Sep 2014", 
"Oct 2014", "Nov 2014", "Dec 2014")), `30` = structure(c("-0.521915972", 
"0.721825004", "-0.468360007", "0.696716011", "-0.181444004", 
"0.585435987"), .Names = c("Jul 2014", "Aug 2014", "Sep 2014", 
"Oct 2014", "Nov 2014", "Dec 2014")), `31` = structure(c("0.721825004", 
"-0.468360007", "0.696716011", "-0.181444004", "0.585435987"
), .Names = c("Aug 2014", "Sep 2014", "Oct 2014", "Nov 2014", 
"Dec 2014")), `32` = structure(c("-0.468360007", "0.696716011", 
"-0.181444004", "0.585435987"), .Names = c("Sep 2014", "Oct 2014", 
"Nov 2014", "Dec 2014")), `33` = structure(c("0.696716011", 
"-0.181444004", "0.585435987"), .Names = c("Oct 2014", "Nov 2014", 
"Dec 2014")), `34` = structure(c("-0.181444004", "0.585435987"
), .Names = c("Nov 2014", "Dec 2014")), `35` = structure("0.585435987", .Names = "Dec 2014"), 
`36` = structure(c("1.043239951", "0.722914994", "-0.349180996", 
"0.074822001", "-1.258324027", "1.153113008", "1.344225049", 
"2.703722954", "-1.334722042", "1.17830801", "1.126680017", 
""), .Names = c("May 2013", "Jun 2013", "Jul 2013", "Aug 2013", 
"Sep 2013", "Oct 2013", "Nov 2013", "Dec 2013", "Jan 2014", 
"Feb 2014", "Mar 2014", "Apr 2014")), `37` = structure(c("0.722914994", 
"-0.349180996", "0.074822001", "-1.258324027", "1.153113008", 
"1.344225049", "2.703722954", "-1.334722042", "1.17830801", 
"1.126680017", "", ""), .Names = c("Jun 2013", "Jul 2013", 
"Aug 2013", "Sep 2013", "Oct 2013", "Nov 2013", "Dec 2013", 
"Jan 2014", "Feb 2014", "Mar 2014", "Apr 2014", "May 2014"
)), `38` = structure(c("-0.349180996", "0.074822001", "-1.258324027", 
"1.153113008", "1.344225049", "2.703722954", "-1.334722042", 
"1.17830801", "1.126680017", "", "", ""), .Names = c("Jul 2013", 
"Aug 2013", "Sep 2013", "Oct 2013", "Nov 2013", "Dec 2013", 
"Jan 2014", "Feb 2014", "Mar 2014", "Apr 2014", "May 2014", 
"Jun 2014")), `39` = structure(c("0.074822001", "-1.258324027", 
"1.153113008", "1.344225049", "2.703722954", "-1.334722042", 
"1.17830801", "1.126680017", "", "", "", ""), .Names = c("Aug 2013", 
"Sep 2013", "Oct 2013", "Nov 2013", "Dec 2013", "Jan 2014", 
"Feb 2014", "Mar 2014", "Apr 2014", "May 2014", "Jun 2014", 
"Jul 2014")), `40` = structure(c("-1.258324027", "1.153113008", 
"1.344225049", "2.703722954", "-1.334722042", "1.17830801", 
"1.126680017", "", "", "", "", ""), .Names = c("Sep 2013", 
"Oct 2013", "Nov 2013", "Dec 2013", "Jan 2014", "Feb 2014", 
"Mar 2014", "Apr 2014", "May 2014", "Jun 2014", "Jul 2014", 
"Aug 2014")), `41` = structure(c("1.153113008", "1.344225049", 
"2.703722954", "-1.334722042", "1.17830801", "1.126680017", 
"", "", "", "", "", ""), .Names = c("Oct 2013", "Nov 2013", 
"Dec 2013", "Jan 2014", "Feb 2014", "Mar 2014", "Apr 2014", 
"May 2014", "Jun 2014", "Jul 2014", "Aug 2014", "Sep 2014"
)), `42` = structure(c("1.344225049", "2.703722954", "-1.334722042", 
"1.17830801", "1.126680017", "", "", "", "", "", "", ""), .Names = c("Nov 2013", 
"Dec 2013", "Jan 2014", "Feb 2014", "Mar 2014", "Apr 2014", 
"May 2014", "Jun 2014", "Jul 2014", "Aug 2014", "Sep 2014", 
"Oct 2014")), `43` = structure(c("2.703722954", "-1.334722042", 
"1.17830801", "1.126680017", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", 
""), .Names = c("Dec 2013", "Jan 2014", "Feb 2014", "Mar 2014", 
"Apr 2014", "May 2014", "Jun 2014", "Jul 2014", "Aug 2014", 
"Sep 2014", "Oct 2014", "Nov 2014")), `44` = structure(c("-1.334722042", 
"1.17830801", "1.126680017", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", 
"", ""), .Names = c("Jan 2014", "Feb 2014", "Mar 2014", "Apr 2014", 
"May 2014", "Jun 2014", "Jul 2014", "Aug 2014", "Sep 2014", 
"Oct 2014", "Nov 2014", "Dec 2014")), `45` = structure(c("1.17830801", 
"1.126680017", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", ""), .Names = c("Feb 2014", 
"Mar 2014", "Apr 2014", "May 2014", "Jun 2014", "Jul 2014", 
"Aug 2014", "Sep 2014", "Oct 2014", "Nov 2014", "Dec 2014"
)), `46` = structure(c("1.126680017", "", "", "", "", "", 
"", "", "", ""), .Names = c("Mar 2014", "Apr 2014", "May 2014", 
"Jun 2014", "Jul 2014", "Aug 2014", "Sep 2014", "Oct 2014", 
"Nov 2014", "Dec 2014")), `47` = structure(c("0.297455013", 
"-2.498219013", "-1.982529998", "0.710475028", "2.43479991", 
"-1.629583001", "3.825987101", "1.375319004", "0.468528003", 
"-1.180858016", "-0.791706979", "0.260260999"), .Names = c("Sep 2005", 
"Oct 2005", "Nov 2005", "Dec 2005", "Jan 2006", "Feb 2006", 
"Mar 2006", "Apr 2006", "May 2006", "Jun 2006", "Jul 2006", 
"Aug 2006")), `48` = structure(c("-2.498219013", "-1.982529998", 
"0.710475028", "2.43479991", "-1.629583001", "3.825987101", 
"1.375319004", "0.468528003", "-1.180858016", "-0.791706979", 
"0.260260999", "1.613098025"), .Names = c("Oct 2005", "Nov 2005", 
"Dec 2005", "Jan 2006", "Feb 2006", "Mar 2006", "Apr 2006", 
"May 2006", "Jun 2006", "Jul 2006", "Aug 2006", "Sep 2006"
)), `49` = structure(c("-1.982529998", "0.710475028", "2.43479991", 
"-1.629583001", "3.825987101", "1.375319004", "0.468528003", 
"-1.180858016", "-0.791706979", "0.260260999", "1.613098025", 
"0.493414998"), .Names = c("Nov 2005", "Dec 2005", "Jan 2006", 
"Feb 2006", "Mar 2006", "Apr 2006", "May 2006", "Jun 2006", 
"Jul 2006", "Aug 2006", "Sep 2006", "Oct 2006")), `50` = structure(c("0.710475028", 
"2.43479991", "-1.629583001", "3.825987101", "1.375319004", 
"0.468528003", "-1.180858016", "-0.791706979", "0.260260999", 
"1.613098025", "0.493414998", "0.659148991"), .Names = c("Dec 2005", 
"Jan 2006", "Feb 2006", "Mar 2006", "Apr 2006", "May 2006", 
"Jun 2006", "Jul 2006", "Aug 2006", "Sep 2006", "Oct 2006", 
"Nov 2006"))), .Names = c("1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", 
"8", "9", "10", "11", "12", "13", "14", "15", "16", "17", "18", 
"19", "20", "21", "22", "23", "24", "25", "26", "27", "28", "29", 
"30", "31", "32", "33", "34", "35", "36", "37", "38", "39", "40", 
"41", "42", "43", "44", "45", "46", "47", "48", "49", "50"))
```

Comment: Do you want to keep the name attribute associated with the number, or do you only want to keep the number? As in, "-3.531716108" has the name attribute "May 2012"

Comment: Only the numbers, as it will ideally just be in the standardized n*12 dataframe

Comment: The first issue you have is a 12 column dataframe doesn't particularly make sense since each list is capturing 12 months rolling forward. So if you limited it to 12 columns, you'd be having, say, June 2013 the same as June 2014, given the conceptual framework I've been thinking to answer your question.

Comment: Yes, agreed. For these purposes, though, I'd just like to calculate the value and then I'll cbind it back together with its characterizing columns, so I'll see the start month from which these values roll.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's an answer using base R.

```
df <- as.data.frame(do.call("rbind", lapply(yourList, function(x) {
  x2 <- as.numeric(x[x != ""])
  vec <- rep(NA, 12)
  vec[1:length(x2)] <- x2
  return(vec)
})))
```

Comment: Thanks. Works quickly and effectively. Is there a reason you chose to populate with NAs into vec?

Comment: Glad it works for you. I used NA because it is R's way of handling missing data, and you asked for blank values. Using "" is not technically blank; it's an empty string. Using "" would also run into problems if you ever wanted to do numeric operations on the values in the data frame, because the numbers were represented as strings.

Answer (score 1):

please allow me to reduce your example to an acceptable size:

```
my_list <- structure(list(
A = structure(c("3.631412983", "1.351914048", "-1.82656002", "-3.531716108", "0.468971014", "-0.510936022", "2.025001049", "4.369469166", "0.574441016", "-0.397388995", "3.314476013", "2.016448021"), .Names = c("Feb 2012", "Mar 2012", "Apr 2012", "May 2012", "Jun 2012", "Jul 2012", "Aug 2012", "Sep 2012", "Oct 2012", "Nov 2012", "Dec 2012", "Jan 2013")), 
B = structure(c("0.721825004", "-0.468360007", "0.696716011", "-0.181444004", "0.585435987"), .Names = c("Aug 2014", "Sep 2014", "Oct 2014", "Nov 2014", "Dec 2014")),
C = structure(c("-1.334722042", "1.17830801", "1.126680017", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", ""), .Names = c("Jan 2014", "Feb 2014", "Mar 2014", "Apr 2014", "May 2014", "Jun 2014", "Jul 2014", "Aug 2014", "Sep 2014", "Oct 2014", "Nov 2014", "Dec 2014"))))
```

to transform the data, i would recommend dplyr and tidyr and use stack (utils), mutate (dplyr) and separate (tidyr)

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
  my_tidy_list <- my_list %>% 
  stack %>% 
  mutate(names = my_list %>% unlist %>% names) %>% 
  separate(names, into = c("id", "month", "year"), sep = "\\.|\ ") %>%
  select(-ind) %>%
  print
```

this way you would end up with a long table format which could be more useful for downstream plotting with ggplot2. if you anyhow prefer a wide table, use spread in addtion:

```
my_tidy_list %>% 
  spread(month, values)
```

Comment: Thank you for this solution; unfortunately i cannot install dplyr on this console, though it is great when i can use it

Answer (score 0):

You can use this approach in bas R:

```
# the number of columns
maxcol <- max(sapply(test99transfer, length))
# create a list of one-row matrices
matlist <- lapply(test99transfer, 
                  function(x) unname(t(c(x, rep("", maxcol - length(x))))))
# create a data frame
dat <- as.data.frame(do.call(rbind, matlist))
```

Comment: @Tony I simplified the answer. Now, additional packages aren't needed.

Comment: Sven, sorry to continue nagging, but this presents a good learning opportunity (of which i need many...). Is there intuition for why this set of functions is much more memory-intensive than the solution provided by Reed below?

Comment: @Tony, Sven's answer makes a copy of test99transfer called matlist, then coverts this to a data frame called dat. In my answer, I went straight from test99transfer to a data frame without the copy. In general, lists take up a lot of memory because they need to be agnostic about what they can contain, as opposed to data frames requiring one data type per column and a column of a specified length. Making a copy of a list is much more memory-intensive than making a copy of a data frame.

Comment: Understood, that's interesting and really useful.